# Unexpected value after inserting node at the end of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I tried to insert a node at the end of the linked list. The node gets inserted but no matter what value I give to that last node, it always ends up giving me 0(zero) as its value. My c++ code is -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct list{
    int data;
    list *next;
};

list * create(){
    char a;
    int i=1;
    list *move,*start,*temp;
    start=new list();
    temp=start;
    cout<<"Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.\n";
    cin>>a;
    while(a=='y'){
        cout<<"Enter data for node "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>start->data;
       move=new list();
       start->next=move;
       start=start->next;
       i++;
       cout<<"Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.\n";
       cin>>a;
    }
    start->next=NULL;
    return temp;
}

void display(list *ob){
    int i=1;
    while(ob->next!=NULL){
    cout<<"\nData for node "<<i<<" is :"<<ob->data;
    ob=ob->next;
    i++;
} }

void add(list *temp){
while(temp->next!=NULL){
    temp=temp->next;
}
int data;
list *node1=new list();
temp->next=node1;
cout<<"Enter data for new node at the end";
cin>>data;
node1->data=data;
node1->next=NULL;

}

int main(){

list *point=create();
add(point);
display(point);
}
```

My console gives the following output.

```
Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.
y
Enter data for node 1
1
Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.
y
Enter data for node 2
2
Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.
n
Enter data for new node at the end 5

Data for node 1 is :1
Data for node 2 is :2
Data for node 3 is :0
```

Can anyone please explain me the output for node 3. In spite of giving it value of 5 it gives 0 as its output !!!

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: sorry but I didn't got you ?

Comment: That's the usual way to find any bugs in your program. Start it in a debugger, step through line by line and watch how variable values change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not that the last node's value is changing to zero, but that in your create function, you are creating an additional node that you didn't account for, and this node is taking a default value, which is zero.

So your list actually has those values:
1 2 0 5

But the 5 is not getting printed also because of an error in your display functions.

So you have two errors in your code.

1- The while loop in the create function should become something like that:

```
while(a == 'y'){
    cout<<"Enter data for node "<<i<<endl;
    cin>>start->data;
    cout<<"Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.\n";
    cin>>a;

    if (a != 'y')
    {
        break;
    }

    move=new list();
    start->next=move;
    start=start->next;
    i++;
}
```

It doesn't look so neat I know, so if you want you can flip somethings in the code so that it looks neater but does what this code is doing (try it yourself ;) )

2- The display function should become:

```
while(ob!=NULL){
    cout<<"\nData for node "<<i<<" is :"<<ob->data;
    ob=ob->next;
    i++;
}
```

because in your code, the last element is not getting printed.

Regards,

Comment: Thankyou soo much abdul..It was of great help. can you please help me here also- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424861/i-always-run-into-a-infinite-loop-on-running-this-program

Comment: I think you should listen to what they are telling you regarding debugging. It's an incredibly vital skill and it doesn't take much to learn :)

Comment: I'll see if I can answer there though

Comment: Ok dude..just one small thing. Can I do such debugging inside eclipse

Comment: Yes sure, almost all IDE's have debuggers in them

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali: Your display function may be correct in the OP situation..however, it will destroy your original list. So if later, in your code, if you want to retrieve your original list, it would be impossible. It's safe to set a variable to hold the reference of the original list first.

Comment: I don't really understand how this will destroy the original list. Do you mean that it is so because we are moving the ob pointer? but the ob pointer is local to the display function and will not affect the original list

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali: the pointer is the argument in the display function. its passed by pointer, not by value. Run in in the debug mode, and you will see..

Answer (score 0):

As AbdulRahman AlHamali has pointed out, I was wrong to say that the the original list will be destroyed. So, my suggestion has become irrelevant now.

// Irrelevant

Suggestion: set a variable to hold the reference of your list before you move to the next node:

```
void add(list *temp){
    list *temp1 = temp;
    while(temp1->next!=NULL){
        temp1=temp->next; 
    }
    int data;
    list *node1=new list();
    temp1->next=node1;
    cout<<"Enter data for new node at the end";
    cin>>data;
    node1->data=data;
    node1->next=NULL;

    }
```

Comment: I kind of disagree because the temp parameter that is being passed is another pointer and not the same as the pointer of the original list. and when he says temp= temp->next. Only the pointer temp is moving not the pointer of the original list

Comment: Had the paramter temp been a reference to a pointer, then it would definitely be wrong

Comment: This also applies to my answer above

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali: you can disagree with me..thats fine..run it it the debug mode and you can come back and tell me what happened to the original list

Comment: OK I just ran it and found that the original list was not affected. I also called display again after it and it worked.
I do agree that it is not a good programming practice because the code does not look that clear, but technically it is correct.
What is happening when you call the function is that another pointer is created that points to the same position, as the original pointer, then when you say ob= ob->next the other pointer moves to a new position, but the original pointer remains where it was

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAlHamali: Thanks, so I just ran it again in the debug mode  and see it for myself hehe. Yes, the original list is not destroyed. It is my fault to say that it will. Sorry, will edit my answer now. Thanks for pointing out.