# I always run into a infinite loop on running this program.

Tags: c++, linked-list

This code is for the insertion of a node in a linked list after a value/data of "2" is found in the list.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct list{
    int data;
    list *next;
};

list * create(){
    char a;
    int i=1;
    list *move,*start,*temp;
    start=new list();
    temp=start;
    cout<<"Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.\n";
    cin>>a;
    while(a=='y'){
        cout<<"Enter data for node "<<i<<endl;
        cin>>start->data;
       move=new list();
       start->next=move;
       start=start->next;
       i++;
       cout<<"Do u want to enter a new node. Press y but anything.\n";
       cin>>a;
    }
    start->next=NULL;
    return temp;
}

void display(list *ob){
    int i=1;
    while(ob->next!=NULL){
    cout<<"\nData for node "<<i<<" is :"<<ob->data;
    ob=ob->next;
    i++;
} }

void add(list *temp){

while(temp->data!=2){
    temp=temp->next;
}
int data;
list *var=temp;
list *node1=new list();
temp->next=node1;
var=var->next;
node1->next=var;
cout<<"Enter data for new node who's data is 2";
cin>>data;
node1->data=data;
cout<<"data inserted";

}

int main(){

    list *point=create();
    add(point);
    display(point);
}
```

If anyone can help me debug it then it would be a great help. Thankyou.
I am running into infinite loop in the display method. If I run the program without the method add then it runs fine.

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger? What did you find?

Comment: sorry but I don't know how to use debugger :(

Comment: @Shivamaggarwal then this is a great time to learn!

Comment: That is a skill which every programmer *needs* to know. You cannot hope to ask SO to debug your code for you each time you need it. It shouldn't be too hard to find an online tutorial or similar resource for this.

Comment: Thanx guys.. Firstly now I gonna learn debugger basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple modification that would make your code work, in `add(list*)`

```
int data;
list *node1 = new list;
node1->next = temp->next;
temp->next = node1;
```

we set the `next` of `node1` immediately after creating it, then we just set the the value `temp->next` to `node1`.

Comment: Just realized that this is almost the same as the answer of @kvorobiev. The only difference is that I didn't create another `list*` for the `temp->next`.

Comment: can you please explain me how does this lead me to an infinite loop. Instead of using node1->next=temp->next; I just used another variable "var" . I just can't understand how it started running infinite times.

Comment: In your original code `var` and `temp` were actually equal. The moment you invoked `temp->next=node1;`, `var->next` is also `node1`.

Answer (score 1):

After executing of

```
add(point)
```

`point` variable will point to list elem with `data` field equale to 2.
And here

```
list *var=temp;
list *node1=new list();
temp->next=node1;
var=var->next;
node1->next=var;
```

you create infinity loop.
Assume at first `temp` and `var` point to `elem1` and `node1` to new `elemN`.

```
temp->next = node1; // elem1.next ---> elemN
var = var->next; // var(elem1) ---> elemN
node1->next = var; // elemN.next ---> elemN
```

One of possible implementation of `add`

```
void add(list *temp){
    list *var=temp;
    while(var->data!=2){
        var=var->next;
    }
    int data;
    list *node1=new list();
    list *nextelem = var->next;
    var->next=node1;
    node1->next=nextelem;
    cout<<"Enter data for new node who's data is 2";
    cin>>data;
    node1->data=data;
    cout<<"data inserted";
}
```